# cygwin gcc: command not found

Tags: gcc, cygwin

Few months back, everything was running just fine.
Now, running `gcc` gives me an error on `cygwin`.

I have :

1) checked and set the `PATH`  to my `gcc`

2) checked if `gcc` was installed and exist in my bin folder

Any other commands are running just fine!
Where can the problem be?

Comment: What are the permissions of the `gcc` binary? Run `ls -l /bin/gcc`. It should show execute permissions.

Comment: @Jens something like : `lrwxrwxrwx 1 rohan None 21 Apr 17  2013 /bin/gcc -> /etc/alternatives/gcc`

Comment: OK, that's a symbolic link (first character is `l`) that points to another file. Does `/etc/alternatives/gcc` exist? If not, somehow your gcc got uninstalled and you should reinstall it.

Comment: @Jens it exist!! solutions ?

Comment: its damaged ! i guess

Comment: It's likely best to start the installer and reinstall gcc in your desired version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc wants to load a dll, which he can't find.

1) try to start gcc with full path (e.g. /usr/bin/gcc) . What happens?

2) If the error is the same, you could use f.e. the Dependency Walker tool (http://dependencywalker.com) to find what can't be found.

Comment: In this case, the gcc executable is surely found, but at least one of its dlls, can't. You need to track, which is this dll and somehow replace it (or make it foundable again). This is what you could do with this dependency walker utility.

Comment: I think I just dumped myself.During installation, it could not find the cygwin1.dll so I just downloaded it. may be an another version ! :/

Comment: Yes, maybe, but if both of your old and new cygwin1.dll were from a newer cygwin version, it surely won't cause problem. If there is an incompatibility problem, you will see this in dependency walker. Is your cygwin now okay, or not? If yes, please don't forget the accept/upvote. :-)